# stopping css file from loading

Tags: php, wordpress

How could I stop quick-style.css from loading on this site deeswholefoods.com? It slows the whole site.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="quick-style-css" href="http://deeswholefoods.com/wp-content/themes/organic-life/quick-style.php?ver=4.3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I have already tried adding following code to function.php to prevent the css file from loading. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

```
function dequeue_my_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('quick-style-css');
  wp_deregister_style('quick-style-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_quick-style-css');
// add a priority if you need it
// add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_quick-style-css',100);

// Register Style
function custom_styles() {

    wp_deregister_style( 'quick-style-css' );
    wp_register_style( 'quick-style-css', '', false, false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_styles' );
```

Do you know what else could I try?

Comment: did you try to edit your theme's header.php? (wp-content/themes/organic-life/header.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this function : wp_enqueue_style()

Wp add "-css" at the end of the stylesheet id.

Maybe just try to do that :

```
 function custom_styles() {
   // remove "-css" at the end of the stylesheet
    wp_deregister_style( 'quick-style' );
    wp_register_style( 'quick-style', '', false, false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function names for `quick-style-css` don't match. You hook `dequeue_quick-style-css` but then name the function `dequeue_my_css`. Should match like this:

```
function dequeue_quick-style-css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('quick-style-css');
  wp_deregister_style('quick-style-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_quick-style-css');
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, I missed it. Unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue.